# configuring php files in vscode

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I run php files in Apache server. Also, i've added in user settings the code as
***"php.validate.executablePath": "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\php.exe",***

Still, i cant run php files? Help;

Answer (score 0):

You have to install `php debug` extension in visual studio code

Try this

```
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug
```

or you can try below one using `php xdebug` extension(this works for me)

```
http://www.accella.net/knowledgebase/debugging-php-with-visual-studio-code/
```

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests, `php.validate.*` directives are used to configure [linting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/php#_linting) (i.e. parsing PHP source code to detect syntax errors):

> ### Linting
>
> VS Code uses the official PHP linter (php -l) for PHP language diagnostics. This allows VS Code to stay current with PHP linter improvements.

To run PHP scripts from within the editor you have a number of choices or none at all depending on what you want to do exactly. You can run command-line scripts from the [integrated terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal), with an extension like [Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mattn.Runner) or [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner). As far as I know there's no way builtin way to lauch a browser in the *preview* pane that reloads as you save if that's what you mean. And you can certainly configure a [debugger](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/php#_debugging).